# IE Equivalent for CSS display: flow-root

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I currently have some code which is working perfectly in chrome which is using this css property `display: flow-root` but it is failing in IE, changing it to `block` or `flex` is not solving the issue.

So just wanted to check if there is any equivalent for IE for the same property.

Comment: Why are you using `flow-root` is the bigger question? For a clearfix? What about setting `content: "";`, `display: table;` and `clear: both;` in `::after`? That will give you IE8 support.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a clearfix hack to cause the wrapper to clear the floated item.

Here is a sample from https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/RKgevX

Do you want something like this?

CSS.

```
    .container2::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }

    .container {
        border: 2px solid #3bc9db;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #e3fafc;
        width: 400px;
        padding: 5px;
    }


    .item {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #1098ad;
        border: 1px solid #0b7285;
        border-radius: 5px;
        float: left;
    }

    h2 {
        padding: 2em 0 0 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 40px auto;
    }
```

HTML.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container container2">
        <div class="item"></div>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]